# avoiding mutable state with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am learning RxJava and I am having a problem avoiding mutable state.

The problem I am solving is simple: there is an input stream of items and an input stream of item groups. Every item belongs to a group (has a group identifier) and has some data. Each group has an identifier and has some data as well. Many items may belong to the same group. The goal is to combine these input streams into one output stream of (item, group) pairs such that:

- an (item, group) pair is only emitted when both an item and its group are known
- an updated (item, group) pair must be emitted every time updated item data is received
- (item, group) pairs corresponding to all items belonging to a group must be emitted when updated data is received for that group

Here’s a working implementation (ItemWithGroup is a class representing an (item, group) pair):

```
public class StateMutationWithinOperator {
    private Map<Integer, Group> allGroups = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, List<Item>> allItems = new HashMap<>();

    public Observable<ItemWithGroup> observe(Observable<Item> items, Observable<Group> groups) {
        return Observable.merge(
            items.flatMap(this::processItem), 
            groups.flatMap(this::processGroup));
    }

    private Observable<ItemWithGroup> processItem(Item item) {
        allItems.computeIfAbsent(item.groupId, missing -> new ArrayList<>())
                .add(item);

        return Observable.just(allGroups)
                .filter(groups -> groups.containsKey(item.groupId))
                .map(groups -> new ItemWithGroup(item, groups.get(item.groupId)));
    }

    private Observable<ItemWithGroup> processGroup(Group group) {
        allGroups.put(group.id, group);

        return Observable.just(allItems)
                .filter(items -> items.containsKey(group.id))
                .flatMapIterable(items -> items.get(group.id))
                .map(item -> new ItemWithGroup(item, group));
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid having side effects in processItem() and processGroup() by avoiding mutating shared state stored in the allGroups and allItems fields. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a publish(selector) to use can split observables easily. You can put your allGroups/allItems into that publish operator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I understand correctly, your suggestion is to use the publish(selector) operator to split the input streams and use the split input stream both for updating the state and for emitting new output items, e.g.:

`inputGroups.publish(groups -> {
      groups.subscribe(group -> allGroups.put(group.id, group));

      return groups.flatMap(this::processGroup);
    });`

It's nicer, but the publish() operator still has a side effect of mutating allGroups. This may lead to concurrent write to allGroups when two groups are coming from two threads at the same moment.

Comment: Answering to myself: according to the [observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html), the emission in observables must be serialised, so the situation with two group updates happening at the same time is not possible.

But still, we have a side effect inside the publish() method. Is it bad and what problems can it cause?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement based on suggestion from @PhoenixWang:

```
public class StateMutationWithinOperator {
  private Map<Integer, Group> allGroups = new HashMap<>();
  private Map<Integer, List<Item>> allItems = new HashMap<>();

  public Observable<ItemWithGroup> observe(Observable<Item> inputItems,
                                           Observable<Group> inputGroups) {
    Observable<ItemWithGroup> processedItems = inputGroups.publish(groups -> {
      groups.subscribe(group -> allGroups.put(group.id, group));

      return groups.flatMap(this::processGroup);
    });

    Observable<ItemWithGroup> processedGroups = inputItems.publish(items -> {
      items.subscribe(item
          -> allItems
          .computeIfAbsent(item.groupId, missing -> new ArrayList<>())
          .add(item));

      return items.flatMap(this::processItem);
    });

    return Observable.merge(processedItems, processedGroups);
  }

  private Observable<ItemWithGroup> processItem(Item item) {
    return Observable.just(allGroups)
        .filter(groups -> groups.containsKey(item.groupId))
        .map(groups -> new ItemWithGroup(item, groups.get(item.groupId)));
  }

  private Observable<ItemWithGroup> processGroup(Group group) {
    return Observable.just(allItems)
        .filter(items -> items.containsKey(group.id))
        .flatMapIterable(items -> items.get(group.id))
        .map(item -> new ItemWithGroup(item, group));
  }
}
```

It is nicer, but the publish() operator still mutates the shared state. One problem I can see with this is that we may receive an item and a group at the same moment from two different threads and end up reading and writing to the same map concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `SerializedSubject` to ensure that thread safety is observed. Second, use a `ConcurrentMap` to hold intermediate representations; the `compute()` method is primitive and prevents competing insertions. Third, the subscription to the `groupBy()` operator can be enforced to be serial by using `observeOn()`.

Here is a working model:

```
public class ItemWithGroupTest {

    static class Item {
        final Integer id;
        final Integer groupId;
        final Integer value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [id=" + id + ", groupId=" + groupId + ", value=" + value + "]";
        }

        public Item( Integer id, Integer groupId, Integer value ) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.groupId = groupId;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    static class Group {
        final Integer id;
        final Integer value;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Group [id=" + id + ", value=" + value + "]";
        }

        public Group( Integer id, Integer value ) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    static class ItemWithGroup {
        final Item item;
        final Group group;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ItemWithGroup [item=" + item + ", group=" + group + "]";
        }

        public ItemWithGroup( Item item, Group group ) {
            super();
            this.item = item;
            this.group = group;
        }
    }

    private final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger( ItemWithGroupTest.class );
    private SerializedSubject<Item, Item> originItems;
    private SerializedSubject<Group, Group> originGroups;
    private Map<Integer, SerializedSubject<Group, Group>> mapGroups;
    private SerializedSubject<ItemWithGroup, ItemWithGroup> itemGroupOutput;

    @Test
    public void testCreation() throws Exception {

        originGroups.onNext( new Group( Integer.valueOf( 3 ), Integer.valueOf( 42 ) ) );
        originItems.onNext( new Item( Integer.valueOf( 1 ), Integer.valueOf( 3 ), Integer.valueOf( 2 ) ) );
        originItems.onNext( new Item( Integer.valueOf( 2 ), Integer.valueOf( 3 ), Integer.valueOf( 8 ) ) );
        originItems.onNext( new Item( Integer.valueOf( 4 ), Integer.valueOf( 2 ), Integer.valueOf( 13 ) ) );
        originItems.onNext( new Item( Integer.valueOf( 1 ), Integer.valueOf( 3 ), Integer.valueOf( 31 ) ) );
        originGroups.onNext( new Group( Integer.valueOf( 3 ), Integer.valueOf( 44 ) ) );
        originGroups.onNext( new Group( Integer.valueOf( 2 ), Integer.valueOf( 41 ) ) );

    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        originItems = PublishSubject.<Item>create().toSerialized();
        originGroups = PublishSubject.<Group>create().toSerialized();
        mapGroups = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
        itemGroupOutput = PublishSubject.<ItemWithGroup>create().toSerialized();
        itemGroupOutput
                .subscribe( v -> logger.debug( "output is {}", v ) );

        originGroups
                .doOnNext( v -> logger.debug( "input group {}", v ) )
                .subscribe();
        originItems
                .doOnNext( v -> logger.debug( "input item {}", v ) )
                .subscribe();

        originGroups.groupBy( group -> group.id )
                .subscribe( gv -> {
                    Integer key = gv.getKey();
                    gv.subscribe( getMapGroup( key ) );
                } );
        originItems.groupBy( item -> item.id )
                .subscribe( itemsGroupedByGroupId -> {
                    Observable<Item> itemV = itemsGroupedByGroupId.share();
                    itemV
                            .take( 1 )
                            .flatMap( vFirst -> Observable.combineLatest( itemV.startWith( vFirst ),
                                    getMapGroup( vFirst.groupId ),
                                    ( i, g ) -> new ItemWithGroup( i, g ) ) )
                            .subscribe( ig -> itemGroupOutput.onNext( ig ) );
                } );
    }

    public Subject<Group, Group> getMapGroup( Integer key ) {
        return mapGroups.compute( key,
                ( id, obs ) -> obs != null ? obs : BehaviorSubject.<Group>create().toSerialized() );
    }

}
```

You won't be able to avoid mutable state. You can control when and where the mutability appears. In the above code, it appears inside of synchronized regions, such as inside `compute()`, and the `groupBy()` operator.

Comment: Bob, thank you for your suggestion! It is very insightful! The recomendation of controlling mutability instead of trying to avoid it, the usage of serialised subjects and the groupBy() operator are ideas I am going to reflect upon now. I've plugged your implementation to my unit tests. Not only it worked fine at the first attempt, but it also let me find a bug in my own implementation: the Item class doesn't have an id, so Item updates are not handled correctly. I am going to revise my implementation based on your input and come up with a new one. Many thanks!